# Topology checks and error marker

Tags: qgis, topology, overlapping-features

I have a problem in QGIS. I want to find overlapping polygons but not only which polygon overlap with another but the exact node(vertex) that intersect or overlap. The error marker doesn't show you this exact point. It marks the whole polygon.

Do you have any ideas?